# Implementing logging in Metro Application developed using Html/WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, error-log

I need to provide with error logging in my Windows 8 Metro application developed in Html/WinJS
so that user can get to know what went wrong from a log file located in the app's local folder.

I have checked WinJS.log(message, tags, type); which will write to the console but not able to find anything via which i can get it on a local file.

What is the best way to do the same and if there are any 3rd party libraries/js available for error logging in metro applications developed in WinJS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WiredPrarie covered use of WinJS.log quite well--the key thing is that you can replace the default behavior however you like. As for logging SDKs, check out the analytics section of http://services.windowsstore.com. There are SDKs available like Localytics, Adobe Omniture, and MarkedUp, which you can readily tie into your WinJS.log implementation.

Answer (score 8):

`WinJS.log` is just a placeholder. Without proper initialization it does nothing (in fact, it's not set at all). If you just call `WinJS.Utilities.startLog()` at your application startup, it defaults to wiring up a logger for the console.

If you want something more complete, you'll need to build it. I've built a small sample below.

```
function startFileLog() {
    // choose where the file will be stored:
    var fileDestination = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;

    var logger = new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
        var logfilename = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:-]/g, "");
        logfilename = "log-" + logfilename + ".log";
        fileDestination.createFileAsync(logfilename,
            Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName)
              .done(function (file) {
                complete(file);
            });
    });

    var actionFn = function (message, tag, type) {
        logger.then(function (file) {
            var m = WinJS.Utilities.formatLog(message, tag, type);
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync(file, m).done();
        });
    };

    WinJS.Utilities.startLog({ action: actionFn });
}
```

By calling the `startFileLog` function above, it creates a new log file (by using the current Date/time as part of the file name) within a promise. Then, a function called `actionFn` is passed to the `startLog` function. By passing an optional property of the options named `action`, the default "write to console" behavior is overwritten (if you didn't want it overwritten, you could call `startLog` without the action, then copy the function reference from `WinJS.log` and replace it with your own function, and call it as well). When the `log` function is called, it now calls `actionFn` which uses the promise created earlier to verify that the log file is in fact available for writing before continuing. If it's not ready yet, it will be queued. So, this means that even though the file may not be ready immediately, the log will, in the end, contain the results you'd expect. There would be a short period of time where, due to async nature of WinJS, if the application crashed before the file completely opened, that logged items will be missed. You could delay the application startup if you wanted until the file was opened by returning the `logger` promise:

```
function startFileLog() {
    /// ... etc..

   return logger;
}

startFileLog().then(function() {
    // the application can now be assured that the log file is ready to accept
    // writes ... (but again, it's all async, so a write may be missed in 
    // extreme cases) 
});
```

You'd likely want to create a function at the end of your application to clean/close the log file.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks for sharing the code!

Comment: thanks for the code, but it's not working for me. If I run startFileLog in my app.onactivated method, my app crashes and I end up with a log with winjs:scheduler errors in it. For example: `winjs:scheduler: Transitioning job (1) from: running to: blocked`

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question rather than trying to troubleshoot the issue in a comment.